# Connect to container from another container or host using the same name

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with 2 services - a database and an application service, like below. The app connects to the database using a configuration defined in an env file like below.

`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password1@localhost:5432/mydbname`

I want to be able to connect to the db from within the application container and from the host (i.e. from outside of the containers) using the same env file.

E.g. If I run the application server from the **host** using the above environment variable (`localhost` for the db host name) it works.

However, if I run the application server from the application **container** I need to change the db host name in the environment variable to make it work:
`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password1@postgresql:5432/mydbname`

How can I configure docker compose such that I can use the same host in the environment variable to connect from both the host and from the application container?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password1
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - "/var/postgres/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/"

  rails-app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: rails-dockerfile.yml
    image: rails-app:0.1
    links:
      - postgresql
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file: .env

volumes:
  vol-postgres:
```

Comment: Why can’t you have two separate `.env` files, one for each environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze The app container has a 'bind' volume that is the same directory that the host uses. So running the app inside the container or on the host will point to the same `.env` file. The idea is that this setup is for my dev environment where I can run things from the host or within the app container.

Comment: This question IMO makes sense. It is common to have tests which run in container (environment) and you want to debug them on your local machine without that container (i.e. your IDE). If your test runs another docker, you are there. Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot configure your containers for something like that, but you can configure your host.

If you are on Linux or MacOS add an entry to `/etc/hosts` that maps `postgresql` to localhost. Something like:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost postgresql
```

There is a similar file in Windows.

Then you can only use the environment variable pointing to `postgresql`.

However note that giving direct access from the host to your database container is a bad practise. Use it only if there is no better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the note about best practice. This is for my dev environment so I can have different versions of postgres running neatly.